# Aurelia Build Bundle Locations in HTML File

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia CLI (v1.2.0) with webpack (v4.41.0). Running the command `au build --env prod` works well and all necessary files are placed in a `dist` folder relative to the project's root as expected. However, a problem I'm seeing is the following in the generated `.html` file:

```
...
<body aurelia-app="main">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime~app.66066bc9a3f8c86e3d5a.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.bluebird~01be3b92.3dbcbc269195ad05c865.chunk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.setimmediate~a1c951f6.42ef81a6d814b4bc894f.chunk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.process~16c59945.ef28f3259f949d41518b.chunk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.moment~399b027d.9b9b0283b72b7237fb27.chunk.js"></script>
...
```

You see the `src="/file_name_here"` part in these script tags is not going to work as it's looking for files at the root of the main hard disk, not relative to the HTML file. If I add `src="../file_name_here"` then all works fine. Am I missing a webpack configuration somewhere?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your project, you have a `webpack.config.js` file.
there you should find the `baseUrl` property. change it to whatever suits you best.

for example: I want the bundle files to be in the same directory of the `index.html` file, regardless of their respective path on the server. (they will not always be in the root of my server).
so I just change the default `'/'` to `''` (empty string.)

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it. Thanks.